# GRUB boot loader not shown on system startup

Tags: linux, kali-linux, dual-boot, grub

I am using Windows 10 installed on SSD( 256 GB) and Kali Linux Installed on HDD(1 TB), After successful installation of Kali Linux, the GRUB bootloader is not displayed on startup. I am not getting an option to choose Kali Linux or Windows 10 during startup. The system directly boots to Windows 10 even though I already installed Kali Linux on the system.

How can I get option to choose Kali Linux or Windows 10 during startup?[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to do what you want to do, Kali is most probably not the Linux distribution you are looking for.

Usually Kali is used as an image stored on an external device that you use to boot your machine or as a virtual machine you start from your main OS (you can use Virtualbox which is free).

Be it as it may be, if you still want to continue that path then your problem might be Grub not being installed in your boot drive.

- Which of those two drives is the one your system boots from?
- Is Grub installed in that drive? Did you choose that drive when installing kali?
- If it isn't you will have to install it by manually in that drive or install Kali again selecting the right drive to install Grub on to.
- Did you choose the right drive but confused drive/partitions?

Don't confuse partitions with drives, Grub needs to be installed in a drive (/dev/sda for instance), not in a partition (/dev/sda1, /dev/sda2, etc...).

One thing is installing the OS (Kali in your case) and another is installing Grub (which -as stated before- has to be in the boot drive).

There are many guides to learn all this stuff, but Kali is going to be too much for you if you don't know how to do this basic things.

**Addendum:**
As stated before you can find tons of howtos/manuals/guides placing a simple search in your google/duckduck/whatever search engine, so I will guive some basic guidelines.

When your computer starts it is your computer's BIOS what initiates the booting process, it makes basic diagnosys and stuff and then (according to the configuration you have set up in your BIOS) select where to boot from.

Once it finds the device where to boot from then it passes control to the piece of code contained in the MBR/GPT, which is a basic code that continues with the initialization. That is the place where Grub should be installed. If it is not, then your Grub piece of code is not in the right place.

Since you asked for guides, this [Arch Partitioning guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Partitioning) might be of interest, you can also check [Wikipedia's booting article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting).

Those are results from simple searches like "linux partitioning boot drive" or "computer boot process", There are some processes that need complete articles to be explained and could hardly be done here.

Comment: Can you please suggest me your recommended guide to learn that stuff??

Comment: I really need kali, Cause I want to know how to work with kali linux

Comment: I have edited the post with an addendum.

Comment: Can I install GRUB boot loader, as  mentioned in this video :- https://youtu.be/rwkCmP-W_lc see from 8:05

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you change the default UEFI boot entry from `Windows Boot Manager` to `kali`, either permanently in the BIOS boot preferences 
or manually via a BIOS hotkey like <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> (depends on the manufacturer) on startup. With `grub`, you should be able to boot both OSes.

Comment: Can I install GRUB boot loader, as  mentioned in this video :- https://youtu.be/rwkCmP-W_lc see from 8:05

Comment: Yes, this is a way to make a legacy Linux installation UEFI bootable.